# Exercises to prevent eyes tiring

Tags: torah-study, medicine, health-safety-shmira, see-sight-vision-blind

It often happens to me that after learning the whole day and reading lots of text especially with small letters I feel my eyes very tired. Who knows good set of exercises that don't takes lot of time, that helps to prevent eyes tiring.

Comment: There is much info online about eye exercises for those who stare at computer screens a lot. I don't know that they'd work for small-type books.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question on Judaism.

Comment: @ArielK, by all means click the "close" link, voting to close it as off-topic. See also [the FAQ](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Comment: @ArielK Can you provide more insight on why you think it's off-topic. After all, isn't it about Jewish Life?

Comment: There's no hashkafic or halachik issue being asked, and reading isn't something specific to Judaism.

Comment: @ArielK cf. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2326.

Comment: @ArielK But many of the questions in [tag:product-recommendation] are also not halacha and hashkafah. I think we ought to allow questions that are particular to Jewish life (in this case learning texts for many hours). Perhaps we should raise this on [meta]?

Comment: If you wait long enough you can post the question [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6160/health).

Comment: At least product recommendations are specifically Jewish and cannot be asked elsewhere,( and most are Torah-related) but this is just a general health tip question. But it makes little difference either way.

Comment: @yydl: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/262

Comment: @yydl This reminds me of a batch of questions from early days of SO: "What is your favorite food... *as a programmer*?" "What music is best... *for a programmer*?" "Which is the most effective coffee... *for a programmer*?". Just because it is relevant to you, doesnt mean its relevant specifically as a result of your Judaismness.

Comment: @All. The site is about Jewish Life and *Learning* so this is not my specific question it's about learning in general.

Comment: @Ariel Spending hours at a time reading fine print on a page is not something that comes up in many other contexts. It seems to me that this is a concern that comes up specially (if not quite uniquely) for people who spend a lot of time learning Torah.

Comment: Depending on how http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/262/the-parameters-of-jewish-life-scope turns out, I may re-open this question.

Comment: The voting there seems to support keeping stuff like this in-scope, so I've re-opened it. That's not to say that the meta discussion is closed.

Comment: How about (in the future for reprints) having books with larger print? But then number of pages would go up, so maybe as another version of the same book

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to WikiHow on Eye Exercise to reduce eye strain: [How to Exercise Your Eyes.](http://www.wikihow.com/Exercise-Your-Eyes)

A Google search for "exercises to reduce eye strain" yielded many helpful results.

Please let us know if you have tried any of these and how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Another page with eye exercises:
http://eyepitstop.com