# How to deal with back pain

Tags: parts-of-the-body, health-safety-shmira

Part of the deal with leaning over sefarim for three sedarim necessarily results in painful shoulder knots or other forms of back pain. What do you all recommend for coping with such symptoms, or how to treat and get rid of them?

---

**The following is not part of the question.** This is only present to preempt anyone who disputes the on-topic-ness of this question.

See also [this related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8548/9682) about eye strain and [this meta discussion](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/262/9682) about posts such as these.

Comment: I don't see that that meta discussion generally supports the claim that this question is on topic. I'm not sure this meets Isaac's second criterion, nor the final points of anon's answer, nor Monica's (though that is somewhat vague), nor mevaqesh's and AviD's obviously. Does anyone have reason to suspect this would get a different answer on Health.SE? What reason is that?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think it does indeed meet both of Isaac's criteria. As illustrated by Shimon's answer, there's several ways that Jews specifically would be able to give ideas.

Comment: Nothing in Shimon's answer seems related to the fact that he's a Jew. Not sitting as much and seeing a therapist are the most generic non-Jewish things to say.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was referring to the shtender, but I suppose you're right. Though may I ask how this is different than the eye strain question?

Comment: Isaac justified the eye question with "However, the special nuance in the Torah study case is that it comes especially from hours of reading small, sometimes blurry print on paper" and anon did by "Torah study may be different from secular reading insofar as you may not be able to hold the book closer to your eyes; it is likely to be an old, printed book rather than a computer or Kindle; you can't deface the book; and you can't necessarily read it in the room with the best light." Personally Im not so convinced. But that is the kind of argument I sought above when I said "What reason is that?"

Comment: @DoubleAA And unlike an ordinary novel, you can't necessarily hold a thick Bava Basra for hours on end in a comfortable position. Which is where the shtender comes in to play. (Please don't argue that textbooks can also be big and bulky. I don't think anything can top Oz V'hadar's Bava Basra in thickness.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seeking for a medical advice is linked to the physical health of the asker. He needs to consult his physician.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important thing that I would recommend is *not* leaning over sefarim for three sedarim. Sitting is the new smoking, as they say. Why not try standing up and using a shtender every so often? Or using a small, portable table-top shtender so that you don't need to lean forwards? Changing up your posture and position every so often will reduce strain on your back and neck, and is generally a healthier option than physical inactivity anyway.

As a *bedieved* solution, I would recommend seeing a good physiotherapist who can provide you with exercises that you might be able to do every evening before bed, every morning on awakening, or at a time of the day that suits your learning schedule. But as they say: prevention is always preferable to a cure!